# Vector from data.table column with specified rows

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to get a vector but I get a data.table :

```
dt["AAPL", Return]
      symbol     Return
   1:   AAPL -0.3499903
   2:   AAPL  0.6496702
   3:   AAPL  1.0987923
   4:   AAPL -0.5235654
   5:   AAPL -0.2456037
  ---                  
2515:   AAPL  0.5715199
2516:   AAPL  0.4495800
2517:   AAPL  4.5469388
2518:   AAPL  1.2327416
2519:   AAPL  0.3210801
```

How to get a vector from data.table column with specific rows ?

Comment: In version 1.9.3 what you tried would work as you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$` as usual (if you are using a version earlier than version 1.9.3 (thanks @GSee, for the comment).

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(v1 = c("A", "B"), v2 = 1:10, key = "v1")
DT["A", ]$v2
# [1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

If you are using the present development version, your approach would work:

```
## if required...
require(devtools)
install_github("Rdatatable/data.table")

packageVersion("data.table")
# [1] ‘1.9.3’

DT["A", v2]
# [1] 1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: You don't need a comma in `DT["A", ]$v2`. Another possible way is to use `[[`, something like `DT["A"][[2]]`